# 3SAT to 1-in-3SAT reduction with additonal constraints

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

The simplest Reduction for 3-SAT to 1-in-3-SAT reduction is as follows:

For each 3SAT clause: $x+y+z=1$ Introduce 4 new variables ${a,b,c,d}$ and replace original clause with below 3 clauses:

$R(x−,a,b)=1$

$R(y,b,c)=1$

$R(z−,c,d)=1$

Query: Given a 3SAT instance how can we reduce it into (as simple as possible) 1-in-3SAT instance with the following additional constraints:

1. All new variables occur in at least 2 clauses.
2. There are no *dummy/redundant* clauses in the new/reduced 1-in-3-SAT. A *dummy/redundant* clause is whose addition or removal in the problem does not change the set of solutions of the problem. Thus, all clauses are *essential*.

I have been stuggling with this for some time without any success. Can someone please help?

P.S. This question was also posted here (https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/50452/3sat-to-1-in-3sat-reduction-with-additonal-constraints) but I did not get an answer.

Comment: can anyone please comment?

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.

Comment: the reason it was cross posted was it didn't get much response there. And it is closed here too :(